# Is OpenCart hardened against the OWASP top 10?

Tags: php, opencart, owasp

I found the 'Testing guide', but it numbers [300 pages](https://www.owasp.org/images/5/56/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3.pdf). It would be nice to read it and test for myself, but I'd like to know if someone has already done this work. I found a [thread](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12043#p59061) on the OC forum about PCI Compliance when I searched about this, but that's a tangential matter.

So does anyone know, *specifically*, if OpenCart is hardened against the OWASP top 10 threat list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, and from my poor testing (and because I know how the OC is written), I could say, that **base OC** (without any 3<sup>rd</sup> party extensions) is safe from:

- **broken access control**
- all user **input is validated**, thus **safe from SQL** or other **injection**
- **XSS**
- **insecure cryptographic storage** - OC does not store any sensitive data and default online payment options are processed via SSL
- **DoS** (indirectly - nowadays server firewalls distinguish a DoS attack and block the communication from that IPs)
- **insecure direct object references** (only allowed types of resources could be uploaded and downloaded unless direct access to an FTP)
- **security misconfiguration** - OC config files are not accessible, users should keep their stores up to date themselves...

What I did not check/encounter so far:

- **Buffer overflow** due to a foreign language (different encoding set) input

Weaker points (**not defects!**):

- OC **frontend** is not well protected against **CSRF**, backend is
- **session management** - problem with possibility of decrypting the session information is the same as over the 95% of web applications
- until directly set/unset, OC will report and **display** any **error message** that may occur that helps an attacker to easily find possible exploits...

**From my view, OC is very well safe-written open source e-commerce solution!** <sub>(Unless compromited with a poorly written extensions...)</sub>